# pandas change dataframe while iterating the same

Tags: python, pandas, statistics, mean

I am a beginner with Pandas.
Use case is, I have two dataframes one containing actual data(say df1) :

```
    teamID  yearID  W   1B PAR      2B PAR      3B PAR      HR PAR       BB PAR
1366    LAA 1961    70  0.147748    0.035708    0.003604    0.030958    0.111548
1367    KC1 1961    61  0.164751    0.035982    0.007829    0.014993    0.096618
1377    NYA 1962    96  0.167148    0.038536    0.004656    0.031952    0.093770
1379    LAA 1962    86  0.159482    0.038027    0.005737    0.022455    0.098672
1381    CHA 1962    85  0.165797    0.040756    0.009129    0.014998    0.101076
```

I need to mean center the data per year. To achieve, I have created a separate frame using below command to have per year mean (say df2)

```
df2 = df1.groupby('yearID').mean()
df2 = df1.reset_index() #not mandatory in this case!
df2.head()

  yearID    W            1B PAR      2B PAR      3B PAR       HR PAR    BB PAR
0   1961    65.500000   0.156249    0.035845    0.005717    0.022975    0.104083
1   1962    78.454545   0.165632    0.035853    0.006777    0.023811    0.088590
2   1963    78.142857   0.162467    0.034020    0.006896    0.021254    0.080336
3   1964    81.727273   0.167251    0.036336    0.006748    0.021548    0.079152
4   1965    82.000000   0.160042    0.035539    0.006534    0.022693    0.085745
```

Now, to mean center df1, i am running below for loop:

```
for i, row in df1.iterrows():
    year = df2[df2['yearID']==row[1]]
    row = row-year
    print(row)
df1.head()
```

Interestingly, print(row) prints updated column values but at the end,df1.head() prints the original dataframe as it is. This makes sense because when we are changing "row" variable, we are actually changing a snapshot/instance and not actual dataframe's content.

Expected output: per year mean of columns 1B PAR, 2B PAR....BB PAR should be equal to 0.

```
Two questions :
> How do I update my dataframe(df1 in above case) as well? 
> Is there a way to subtract just the subset of columns and not all of them? Current code is subtracting yearId as well but we'd want to center just (1B PAR:BB PAR) columns
```

Thanks!

---

PS: I just modified my for loop and i am now getting the expected results :

```
for i, row in df1.iterrows():
    year = df2[df2['yearID']==row[1]]
    row = row-year
    df1.set_value(i,'1B PAR', row['1B PAR'])
    df1.set_value(i,'2B PAR', row['2B PAR'])
    df1.set_value(i,'3B PAR', row['3B PAR'])
    df1.set_value(i,'HR PAR', row['HR PAR'])
    df1.set_value(i,'BB PAR', row['BB PAR'])
df1.head()

     teamID yearID     W     1B PAR      2B PAR     3B PAR     HR PAR    BB PAR
1366    LAA 1961    70  -0.164751   -0.000137   -0.002113   0.007983    0.007465
1367    KC1 1961    61  -0.147748   0.000137    0.002113    -0.007983   -0.007465
1377    NYA 1962    96  -0.164116   0.002683    -0.002121   0.008141    0.005180
```

Is there better way of achieving the same result? I believe this not the most beautiful way of doing what is done!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Different approach:

```
msuf = '_mean'
dfm = pd.merge(df1,df2,on="yearID",suffixes=('',msuf))
for column in ["1B PAR","2B PAR","3B PAR","HR PAR","BB PAR"]:
    dfm[column] = dfm[column] - dfm[column+msuf]
    dfm = dfm.drop(column+msuf,axis=1)
```

First you merge the two dataframes on `yearID`, then do your subtractions column-wise and drop the mean-columns.

Comment: Please remember to accept my answer if it solves your problem.